Consistent feedback options for review
I was going through and reviewing questions and answers and noticed something. The feedback options are not consistent throughout. For example here are the options for each review category:



First answers
First questions












Late answers
Triage









Notice something? The options are not consistent!
Let me give an example of why this is a handicap to reviewers:

A reviewer goes to the review queue to review late answers
The question is How to center a div in css
A new user leaves an answer like this:

.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}


This answer works but provides no additional information. I want add an automatic comment Answer needs supporting information
I cannot do this in the late answer queue. I am now forced to
a. Skip the answer
b. Leave a comment myself

Neither of these are a good solution. If I skip I'm not being a helpful reviewer and if I leave a comment new users my not take as seriously or as well as they should.
I have already posted about this on Meta. Here is a helpful answer explaining more in depth why this is unsatisfactory. However, I believe there is a solution.
Proposal
TLDR:
The review queues should be broken in to categories: questions and answers. Everything in the questions category should have the same options. Same thing for answers.
The questions category should contain the following options:

Looks OK:
This question can be understood and answered as-is (be sure to vote accordingly).
Edit:
Improve and correct problems with this question yourself.
Share feedback:
Leave a helpful comment for the new poster.
Suggest deletion closure:
This question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow.
Other action:
You have taken one or more actions on this question and have finished your review.

The answers category should contain the following options:

Looks OK:
This answer is good as-is and not low quality (be sure to vote accordingly).
Edit:
Improve and correct problems with this answer yourself.
Share feedback:
Leave a helpful comment for the new poster.
Suggest deletion:
This answer is not a good fit for Stack Overflow.
Other action:
You have taken one or more actions on this answer and have finished your review.

Sources:
Missing option to request an edit to provide more details in late answer review

'First Answers' and 'Late Answers' should share the same options indeed, (=> both with 'Edit', 'Feedback' and 'Deletion'), but 'Deletion' shouldn't be there for 'First Questions', one (or more) DV('s) and 'Roomba' will deal with that Qt.

Nitpick: "Suggest deletion" for questions should be closure, not deletion.

@RyamM Agreed. Changed that.

This post is kind of hard to scroll through. Would it perhaps be better if those screenshots were bullet lists instead? It'd be less aesthetically pleasing, but maybe more convenient.

Actually, triage might actually be fine as-is. Since it uses a consensus mechanism instead of a one-reviewer mechanism, it probably needs a different set of options. (Did you lump it in with the questions queues? I couldn't tell.)

@AndrewYim Yes triage is in the questions queue. Just curious as to why these options wouldn't work on a consensus base already? Perhaps that is too big of a change and triage can be kept the same for now.

@Ethan The edit option might not work so well, for example, since several people probably won't come to an independent consensus as to what the edit should be. Also, triage is supposed to be faster than the other queues IIRC? And having edit/comment options might slow it down.

@AndrewYim Good point. However, I still think the to comment would be nice. Maybe it could be put somewhere different.

"New poster". I just noticed that. I hate it that even the UI is oddly specific. No. Just "the author" will do.
